# Apply theme to all Dialogs in an Android application

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-theme, android-styles

I need to change the style for every single dialog in my application.  My understanding, after reading through the Styles and Themes documentation (which is fairly poor, really), I came up with this snippet:

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="RMTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
        <item name="android:dialogLayout">@style/CustomDialog</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent_color</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

This should, if properly applied, create every dialog with a transparent background and black text.

Here's where I apply the theme.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <application 
      android:theme="@style/RMTheme"
      android:debuggable="true" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" 
      android:icon="@drawable/icon">
```

I'm guessing the problem lies in the way I'm trying to apply my own namespace's `Theme.Dialog` to the android namespace's `Theme.Dialog`.  Basically, and I think this is clear from the code, I just want to add/override some properties in android's default dialog style.

EDIT: Note also that I do not want to (and in fact cannot, since I'm compiling for API level 9) use the `Dialog(Context context, int style)` constructor.  I want to apply the theme globally without explicity passing the theme id to every dialog constructor, and furthermore, it's not available to me at this API level anyway.

EDIT: Woops... apparently `Dialog(Context context, int style)` IS available at this API level.  It was `AlertDialog(Context context, int style)` I was thinking of.  Nonetheless, I still want to apply this theme globally for all dialogs rather than having to use that constructor.

Comment: give it a try by using some different name like `CustomTheme.Dialog` instead of `Theme.Dialog`.because you are trying to create a subclass of itself with same name.Inshort,parent and child both are `Theme.Dialog`,weird!!

Comment: actually that's not the case if you understand how the naming works in android... nonetheless, i tried your suggestion just for giggles.  no change in behavior.

Comment: @moonlightcheese *ping*

Answer (score 1):

### Solution for API level 8, EDIT

`android:dialogLayout` does not exist in **API 8** if you look at `themes.xml` included with the Android SDK. You can find all relevant xml files under **"Android SDK Folder"/platforms/android-8/data/res/values**

This is the only property in `style/Theme` for that API level that is related to `Dialog`.

```
    <!-- Dialog attributes -->
    <item name="alertDialogStyle">@android:style/AlertDialog</item>
```

That then references to this:

```
<style name="AlertDialog">
    <item name="fullDark">@android:drawable/popup_full_dark</item>
    <item name="topDark">@android:drawable/popup_top_dark</item>
    <item name="centerDark">@android:drawable/popup_center_dark</item>
    <item name="bottomDark">@android:drawable/popup_bottom_dark</item>
    <item name="fullBright">@android:drawable/popup_full_bright</item>
    <item name="topBright">@android:drawable/popup_top_bright</item>
    <item name="centerBright">@android:drawable/popup_center_bright</item>
    <item name="bottomBright">@android:drawable/popup_bottom_bright</item>
    <item name="bottomMedium">@android:drawable/popup_bottom_medium</item>
    <item name="centerMedium">@android:drawable/popup_center_medium</item>
</style>
```

These are different 9 patch drawables, the OS selects it based on your theme, Froyo offered a few such as `Theme.Black` and `Theme.Light`.

For API level 8, that´s it! The only thing you seem to be able to change via XML are those images relating to the dialog's background. Newer OS versions allow you to override the `alertDialogTheme` attribute, which gives you much more control via XML.

#### API 8 background change

I make an ultra simple `AlertDialog`

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("TESTING 123");
    builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               }
           });
    builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               }
           });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

This is how it looks on a Gingerbread device (too lazy to create a Froyo emulator...)

[image: Before change]

Now we override the alert dialog style via the XML.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:style/Theme">

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/NewAlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="NewAlertDialog">
    <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

We add the theme to the `application` tag in the manifest file.

Now the Dialog looks like this:
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"

[image]

Comment: wrong.  those properties have changed between the various versions of Android.  that is why i gave reference to a specific API level multiple times in the question.  those properties don't exist in the style/theme resources in android-8.

Comment: Actually, even if you read over your question multiple times you will find that it contains only one reference to API level 9. I will edit my response for API level 8.

Comment: did you try this code?  does it work?  i remember reading exactly this, trying it, and failing.  if you did get it to work at some point, a pastebin would be awesome (including where you include the theme - which i'm guessing should be in the AndroidManifest - as well as the full xml and java source for the files).  thanks for the help.

Comment: I have used something similar successfully in the past. I will take a look and give you a step-by-step solution as soon as I get a pestering client of my back, i.e. tomorrow!

Comment: i ended up not using the AlertDialog class and replaced it with a plain jane Dialog with the stuff i needed.  it's fugly.  i'll get around to trying this at some point since you took the time to leave such a detailed answer. ^_^  i'll accept it once i confirm it works.

Answer (score -1):

Another trick is this:

Instead of

```
new Dialog(getApplicationContext(), ...)
```

Do

```
new Dialog(MyActivity.this, ...)
```